# Fiddler - Easily copy webservice XML requests/responses with color syntax highlighting and formatting

Tags: fiddler

I use Fiddler to debug webservices and when I need to share a particular webservice request and response over email, I would copy the request/response into Visual Studio for color syntax highlighting and formatting and paste it into an Outlook email client.

Is there a plugin that would do color syntax highlighting and formatting for me so I can skip the step of pasting the request/responses in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Get the **SyntaxView** Inspector. It's the first extension listed here: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/extensions.asp.